# JQuery Validate - Add/remove error css class in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I want to add/remove the `error` css class in the form.

```
$("#my-form").validate({
        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
            // 'this' refers to the form
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                $(this).addClass("error");
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            }
        },
});
```

**Problem with this approach:**
When I use `$("#my-form").validate().form()` to validate the form, it will automatically add/remove the `error` css-class to each of the controls such as an input. By adding  `invalidHandler` this additionally will add/remove the `error` css-class of the whole form.

Once I do `validator.resetForm()` to clear the messages, this will reset the css-class from the children controls but not from the form. I wish it automatically removes the css-class from the form by using a binding or any other sort of handler that trigger this action (removing the css-class from the form).

How I can fix this problem?

Source: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

**Update**
Here a silly example: http://jsfiddle.net/F2Re4/ and I manually remove the class (in this example, I called the class: 'error-form')

Comment: Not sure what you're taking about.  The `error` class is automatically added and removed by default.

Comment: that is only happen to each element that we are validating but not to the form.

Comment: I have no idea what you want.  Create a jsFiddle demo of what you have so far so I can sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the markup of [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2Re4/),

```
<input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="Validate"></input>
<input type="button" onclick="resetForm()" value="Reset Form"></input>
```

1) `input` elements do not have a closing tag.  They may or may not need to be "self-closing" depending on your `doctype`, but there is never any such thing as an `</input>` tag.

2)  Inline JavaScript is ugly and unnecessary when you use jQuery.  `onclick` handlers can easily be removed and replaced with jQuery `.on('click')`...

```
$('#reset').on('click', function () {
    var form = $("#myForm");
        form.validate().resetForm();
});
```

3)  You do not need a `validate` function attached to your "validate" button.  Simply change the button into a `type="submit"` and it will be validated automatically.  Otherwise, you would need another `.on('click')` handler and a `.valid()` within to trigger a validation test.

```
<input type="submit" id="validate" value="Validate" />
<input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset Form" />
```

---

**Quote OP:**

> ... `validator.resetForm()` to clear the messages, but this `invalidHandler` is never called and the 'error' css class still there in the form.

As per documenation, `invalidHandler` is only called when the form is invalid.   If you reset the form, the form is no longer invalid.  Therefore, the logic used within your `invalidHandler` is flawed.

```
var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
if (errors) {
    $(this).addClass("form-error");
} else {
    // this will never be called because invalidHandler
    // is never called when there are no form errors
    //$(this).removeClass("form-error");
}
```

There is nothing in this plugin that will automatically add/remove the class of the `<form>` element itself.  The plugin only automatically adds/removes classes from the various data input elements.  Therefore, if you manually add a class to the `<form>` element, then you're going to have to manually remove it when you reset the form.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myForm").validate({
        // your rules & options
    });

    $('#reset').on('click', function () {
        var form = $("#myForm");
            form.validate().resetForm();    // reset validation on form
            form.removeClass("form-error"); // remove error class from form
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/F2Re4/11/**

Answer (score 0):

Use `.valid()` to test the form. See the click function for [valid()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid)

```
validate = function(){
    $("#myForm").valid();
};

resetForm = function(){
    var form = $("#myForm").validate();
    form.resetForm();
};
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/tive/U2XKx/

Additionally use `reset()` as seen on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp) to clear the text value.